# A More Powerful getOrElse?

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
val userName = users.get(userID) match {
  case Some(user) => user.name
  case None => "Invalid User ID"
}
```

Is there a more concise way of writing this?

I was wondering if there was something similar to `getOrElse` that would let me apply a function if it is successful (to extract the user name), or return a plain value otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in one method call, but in two:

```
users.get(userID).map(_.name).getOrElse("Invalid User ID")
```

Oops, apparently `Option.fold` was finally added in Scala 2.10, according to @sschaef's answer.

Answer (score 12):

```
scala> Map("a" -> 1).get("a").fold("invalid user id")("value:"+_)
res15: String = value:1

scala> Map("a" -> 1).get("b").fold("invalid user id")("value:"+_)
res16: String = invalid user id
```

`Option.fold` has some problems with type inference, for potential pitfalls see [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321164/option-fold-in-scala-2-10/12321238#12321238) answer.

Comment: Would my example translate to: `users.get(userID).fold("Invalid User ID")(_.name)`?

Comment: Is it that difficult to test it in the REPL? Nevertheless, I think yes it should work that way.

Comment: I am still in 2.9, so it didn't work for me. But it looks really concise. I hope to be able to upgrade soon. Thanks.