# if (Option.nonEmpty) vs Option.foreach

Tags: scala

I want to perform some logic if the value of an option is set.

Coming from a java background, I used:

```
if (opt.nonEmpty) {
   //something
}
```

Going a little further into scala, I can write that as:

```
opt.foreach(o => {
  //something 
})
```

Which one is better? The "foreach" one sounds more "idiomatic" and less Java, but it is less readable - "foreach" applied to a single value sounds weird.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your example is not complete and you don't use minimal syntax. Just compare these two versions:

```
if (opt.nonEmpty) {
  val o = opt.get
  // ...
}

// vs

opt foreach {
  o => // ...
}
```

and

```
if (opt.nonEmpty)
  doSomething(opt.get)

// vs

opt foreach doSomething
```

In both versions there is more syntactic overhead in the `if` solution, but I agree that `foreach` on an `Option` can be confusing if you think of it only as an optional value.

Instead `foreach` describes that you want to do some sort of side effects, which makes a lot of sense if you think of `Option` being a monad and `foreach` just a method to transform it. Using `foreach` has furthermore the great advantage that it makes refactorings easier - you can just change its type to a `List` or any other monad and you will not get any compiler errors (because of Scalas great collections library you are not constrained to use only operations that work on monads, there are a lot of methods defined on a lot of types).

Comment: I like this reasoning. I'd also add that with foreach you never introduce `get()` into your code, which is bad practice with an `Option` even when you properly test for `nonEmpty()`. If you need to do something whether or not the option is empty, `match` with `Some(x)` and `None` cases is the way to go.

Answer (score 10):

`foreach` does make sense, if you think of `Option` as being like a `List`, but with a maximum of one element.

A neater style, IMO, is to use a for-comprehension:

```
for (o <- opt) {
  something(o)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`foreach` makes sense if you consider `Option` to be a list that can contain at most a single value. This also leads to a correct intuition about many other methods that are available to `Option`.

I can think of at least one important reason you might want to prefer `foreach` in this case: it removes possible run-time errors. With the `nonEmpty` approach, you'll at one point have to do a `get`*, which can crash your program spectacularly if you by accident forget to check for emptiness one time.

If you completely erase `get` from your mind to avoid bugs of that kind, a side effect is that you also have less use for `nonEmpty`! And you'll start to enjoy `foreach` and let the compiler take care of what should happen if the `Option` happens to be empty.

You'll see this concept cropping up in other places. You would never do

```
if (age.nonEmpty)
    Some(age.get >= 18)
else
    None
```

What you'll rather see is

```
age.map(_ >= 18)
```

The principle is that you want to avoid having to write code that handles the failure case – you want to offload that burden to the compiler. Many will tell you that you should *never* use `get`, however careful you think you are about pre-checking. So that makes things easier.

---

* Unless you actually just want to know whether or not the `Option` contains a value and don't really care for the value, in which case `nonEmpty` is just fine. In that case it serves as a sort of `toBoolean`.

Comment: In your first code snippet, shouldn't it be `Some(age.get >= 18)` to have an `Option` as the resulting type as well?

Comment: @Beryllium Of course it should! I have no idea how that happened. Probably from too much Python.

Answer (score 3):

Things I didn't find in the other answers:

1. When using `if`, I prefer `if (opt isDefined)` to `if (opt nonEmpty)` as the former is less collection-like and makes it more clear we're dealing with an option, but that may be a matter of taste.
2. `if` and `foreach` are different in the sense that `if` is an expression that will return a value while `foreach` returns `Unit`.  So in a certain way using `foreach` is even more java-like than `if`, as java has a foreach loop and java's `if` is not an expression.  Using a for comprehension is more scala-like.
3. You can also use pattern matching (but this is also also less idiomatic)
4. You can use the `fold` method, which takes two functions so you can evaluate one expression in the `Some` case and another in the `None` case.  You may need to explicitly specify the expected type because of how type inference works (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321164/option-fold-in-scala-2-10/12321634#12321634)).  So in my opinion it may sometimes still be clearer to use either pattern matching or `val result = if (opt isDefined) expression1 else expression2`.

If you don't need a return value and really have no need to handle the not-defined case, you can use `foreach`.

Comment: "As far as I know there is no Option method that will evaluate one expression in the Some case and another in the None case" There is: `opt.fold("None")(v => s"Some($v)")`.