# using if instead of match on Option[X]

Tags: scala, scala-option

I want to replace the below match with an if statement, preferably less verbose than this. I personally find if's to be easier to parse in the mind.

```
val obj = referencedCollection match{
            case None => $set(nextColumn -> MongoDBObject("name" -> name))
            case Some( collection) =>....}
```

Is there an equivalent if statement or some other method that produces the equivalent result?

Comment: If you prefer and want to use `if` in this situation, don't use scala, you will hit a wall soon or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably ought not indulge yourself in continuing to use `if` in conditions like this.  It's not idiomatic, rarely is faster, is more verbose, requires intermediate variables so is more error-prone, etc..

Oh, and it's a bad idea to use anything with `$` signs!

Here are some other patterns that you might use in addition to match:

```
val obj = referenceCollection.fold( $set(nextColumn -> MongoDBObject("name" -> name) ){
  collection => ...
}

val obj = (for (collection <- referenceCollection) yield ...).getOrElse{
  $set(nextColumn -> MongoDBObject("name" -> name)
}

val obj = referenceCollection.map{ collection => ... }.getOrElse{
  $set(nextColumn -> MongoDBObject("name" -> name)
}
```

You can basically think of `map` as the `if (x.isDefined) x.get...` branch of the `if` and the `getOrElse` branch as the `else $set...` branch.  It's not exactly the same, of course, as leaving off the `else` gives you an expression that doesn't return a value, while leaving off the `getOrElse` leaves you with an unpacked `Option`.  But the thought-flow is very similar.

Anyway, `fold` is the most compact.  Note that both of these have a bit of runtime overhead above a `match` or `if` statement.

Comment: *Oh, and it's a bad idea to use anything with $ signs!* It's casbah dsl which tries to be as [close to original mongo](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) as it can. Likely you have to tell this to @brendan-w-mcadams

Comment: I choose fold as it conveys its meaning perfectly and concisely; even if the statement is presented outside it's context.

Comment: Had to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321164/option-fold-in-scala-2-10 and http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option to fully get it.

Answer (score 7):

You can replace the pattern match by a combination of `map` and `getOrElse`:

```
ox match {
  case None => a
  case Some(x) => f(x)
}
```

can be replaced by

```
ox.map(f).getOrElse(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is huge number of options (pun intended):

```
if (referencedCollection != None) { ... } else { ... }
if (referencedCollection.isDefined) { ... } else { ... } // @Kigyo variant
if (referencedCollection.isEmpty) { /* None processing */ } else { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
val obj = if(referencedCollection.isDefined) { (work with referencedCollection.get) } else ...
```